# Scoped css not being applied to SvelteKit on build

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

Okay this is one of the most weirdest bugs I've ever encountered.

When I run my code on `npm run dev`, it runs perfectly, but when I build it as static site, it's acting weird. Like what I want to do is to change the clicked element's color to be green. But what's happening instead is, it is not updating the other element's color on click.

If you think my code logic is wrong then let me tell you it is working fine on dev mode. Here are few screenshots:

[image]
[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

But it's looking like this after `build`:

[image]

My config:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-static';
import { vitePreprocess } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {

    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({
            pages: 'build',
            assets: 'build',
            fallback: null,
            precompress: false,
            strict: true
        })
    }
};

export default config;
```

**Edit:**

Okay, very interesting thing. When I add an empty block like this:

```
button {
}
```

Everything suddenly works perfectly. So weird...

Comment: Just a wild guess, but probably your general button styles are overwriting the .tabactive class? Try throwing some !important attributes into the .tabactive class and see if that works.

Comment: @rx2347 nah it's not that. That's one of the most wildest bugs I have ever scene

Comment: Try `:global(.tabactive) { }` - The class might be removed by the compiler. Modifiying the classList like this is usually not the way to go. If there were code blocks of all relevant code instead of the screenshots it would be possible to show an alternative.

Comment: @Corrl I've posted the answer. It worked but in the svelte way...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like svelte doesn't know my intentions when I'm doing this the vanillaJS way. When I did that in the svelte way, it worked. Basically I had to remove all JS and instead of `classList.add('tabactive')`, I used svelte's own class directive.

Here's how I did that:

```
<button
    on:click={() => (clickedTab = 'resolved')}
    class:tabactive={clickedTab == 'resolved'}
>

<button
    on:click={() => (clickedTab = 'assigned')}
    class:tabactive={clickedTab == 'assigned'}
>

<button
    on:click={() => (clickedTab = 'pending')}
    class:tabactive={clickedTab == 'pending'}
>
```

This replaced the JS implementation of adding/removing class with a simple `if variable == value` check

Based on an answer to a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/sveltejs/comments/138ieah/comment/jj0bh9k/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) from artibonite